# While connecting of my login page to MySql i am getting error of CommunicationException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was creating login page from where entered data will be store at database. But after submitting data it will show error on console. About CommunicationException: Communication link failure.
what are the reasons for this Exception?

```
public class ConnectionProvider {
    static Connection connection=null;
    public static Connection getConn() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/Emdemo","root","root");
        } catch ( Exception e) {
        
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And errors are:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Port 8080 is generally for HTTP servers, and it is extremely unlikely your MySQL server is listeneing on that port. MySQL defaults to port 3306, so use `jdbc:mysql://localhost/Emdemo` or `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Emdemo`.

Comment: no it won't works

Comment: Then you do not have MySQL running, or you need to check the configuration of your MySQL installation to see what port it is using.

Answer (score 0):

try using jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Emdemo